# Equivalent to the Xcode playground in AppCode

Tags: appcode

I can not find any references to running `xcode playgrounds` in `AppCode` so am assuming that were not possible?  Here is what an `xcode playground` looks like in `AppCode`: I am not even sure where to find the source code.

[image]

Is there any way to run/debug a snippet of `swift` code in `AppCode`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a new **command line tool** project with **swift** language, you will get a clean project that can run swift code directly.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can this somehow be used within an existing project?

Answer (score 1):

Playground is not supported in AppCode at this moment (v2022.2): https://www.jetbrains.com/help/objc/ac-mg-xcode-features-unvailable.html